# Como chamar método de classe dentro da thread?

Tags: c++, funções, classes, thread, método

Como faço para chamar um método de classe dentro de uma thread?
Tenho uma thread bem simples e um método de classe. Como faço para chamá-lo dentro da thread. Como está no código abaixo o compilador dá erro

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

class Aviao{
    public:

        int vel = 0;

        void imprime(){ cout << "imressões";} // meu método
};

int main(){

    Aviao *av1=new Aviao();

    thread first(meu_método_imprime()_aqui); // meu método dentro da thread

    first.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: corrija a indentação de seu programa...qualquer programa um pouco maior sem indentação fica mais difícil entender...seu programa é bem simples, dá para entender, mas praticamente não existe programa em C ou C++ (na verdade, em qualquer linguagem) que não use algum tipo de indentação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma lambda:

```
Aviao *av1 = new Aviao();

thread first([av1]{
    av1->imprime();
}); // meu método dentro da thread
```

Ou alternativamente usar a função bind:

```
#include <functional>
...
thread second(std::bind(&Aviao::imprime, av1));
```

Comment: Obrigado user72726